# python - tkinter grid row not appearing and not passing to function correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, grid

Two separate issues have come up with my code

First, I can't get the fourth row of my grid to appear, although the fifth appears to be displaying just fine.

Secondly, my passVal function keeps giving me the error:

```
passVal() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I've tried rearranging things and converting it to a string and nothing seems to work.

I figure there's a chance it's one thing causing the same issue since they're both centered around the same button but I'm not sure.

```
import tkinter

class AccountCreation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main.title("Account Creation")

        self.topleftLabel = tkinter.Label(text="      ")
        self.topleftLabel.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.botrightLabel = tkinter.Label(text="      ")
        self.botrightLabel.grid(row=5,column=5)

        self.promptLabel = tkinter.Label(text="Create a password with at least nine (9)\n characters that contains at least one digit, \n one uppercase, and one lowercase letter.\n\n")
        self.promptLabel.grid(row=2,column=2,columnspan=2)

        self.passLabel = tkinter.Label(text="Password:")
        self.passLabel.grid(row=3,column=2)
        self.passEntry = tkinter.Entry(width = 18, justify='right')
        self.passEntry.grid(row=3,column=3)

        self.enterButton = tkinter.Button(text="Enter", \
                                      command=self.passVal(self.passEntry.get()))
        self.enterButton.grid(row=4,column=2)
        self.cancelButton = tkinter.Button(text="Cancel", \
                                      command=self.cancel)
        self.cancelButton.grid(row=4,column=3)

        tkinter.mainloop()

def passVal(pw):
    if len(pw) < 9:
       print ("no")

def cancel(self):
    self.main.destroy()

my_gui = AccountCreation()
```

Comment: BTW you don't need to use labels for spacing. You can use padding for that.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I don't think this question is a duplicate of the post you referenced. This questions problem was more related to the missing `self` argument in the `passVal` method. Yes there was also the matter of the command execution on init but that was not the main question/problem.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the indention issues you are having, all methods in a class you need to pass self as the first argument unless you are using special tags that can make it a stand alone function.

Change:

```
def passVal(pw):
```

To:

```
def passVal(self, pw):
```

You will also need to change the command on you Enter button to use `lambda` in order to prevent python from calling the `passVal` method on start up.

Change:

```
command=self.passVal(self.passEntry.get())
```

To:

```
command=lambda: self.passVal(self.passEntry.get())
```

You don't really need to use a lambda here or even pass the argument of self.passEntry.get(). You can get the value of the entry field in the `passVal()` method by use `self.passEntry.get()` instead of `pw`.

If you change this:

```
command=lambda: self.passVal(self.passEntry.get())
```

To this:

```
command=self.passVal
```

And this:

```
def passVal(self, pw):
    if len(pw) < 9:
        print ("no")
```

To this:

```
def passVal(self):
    if len(self.passEntry.get()) < 9:
        print ("no")
```

You program will work fine and you can avoid using a lambda in your command.

Note: You do not need to use labels as spacers. You can simple use padx and pady in your grid placement.

Take a look at the below code:

```
import tkinter

class AccountCreation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main.title("Account Creation")

        self.promptLabel = tkinter.Label(text="Create a password with at least nine (9)\n characters that contains at least one digit, \n one uppercase, and one lowercase letter.\n\n")
        self.promptLabel.grid(row=2,column=2,columnspan=2,pady=(10,10))

        self.passLabel = tkinter.Label(text="Password:")
        self.passLabel.grid(row=3,column=2)
        self.passEntry = tkinter.Entry(width = 18, justify='right')
        self.passEntry.grid(row=3,column=3)

        self.enterButton = tkinter.Button(text="Enter", \
                                          command=self.passVal(self.passEntry.get()))
        self.enterButton.grid(row=4,column=2)
        self.cancelButton = tkinter.Button(text="Cancel", \
                                          command=self.cancel)
        self.cancelButton.grid(row=4,column=3,pady=(10,10))

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def passVal(self, pw):
        if len(pw) < 9:
            print ("no")

    def cancel(self):
        self.main.destroy()

my_gui = AccountCreation()
```

Notice that simple using `pady=(10,10)` we have put space at the top and bottom of the widget.